# How to catch an Error for timeout on http.client Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Future that calls a POST API using the http.client structure.

At the moment there is an issue with said API and my call is timing out before the full header is received, giving me a unhandled exception.

How is the best way to return this exception and show a snackbar of the issue returned?

```
  Future<dynamic> get() async {
try {
  var response = await client.post(
    Uri.parse(Url),
    headers: headers,
    body: body,
  );
```

}

Answer (score 1):

here is the simple http call to catch an Error for timeout

return the error and catch this where from you handle the api call

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

Future<dynamic> get() async {
  try {
    var response = await post(
      Uri.parse(Url),
      headers: headers,
      body: body,
    ).timeout(Duration(seconds: 2), onTimeout: (){
      /// here is the response if api call time out
      /// you can show snackBar here or where you handle api call
      return Response('Time out!', 500);
    });
  }catch(e){
    print(e);
  }
}
```

you can change your duration in the timeout method